# Makefile multiple definitions errors

Tags: c, makefile

In my makefile I have

```
readline: readline.h readline.c
    gcc -c -o readline readline.c
car: car.c car.h readline.h
    gcc -c -o car car.c
dealer.o: dealer.c car.h
    gcc -c -o dealer dealer.c
dealer: car.o dealer.o readline.o
    gcc car.o dealer.o readline.o
```

readline.h contains a function prototype that reads in strings that my professor gave us, readline.c is the function,car.c contains a struct with car information, and the various functions for operating on a linked list, dealer.c is where the main function is.

This is my first time with makefiles but I have been getting various errors that are hard to understand saying something about multiple definition of certain functions (some actually in my code and some I guess deep in my code for the system) I don't know why I'm getting these errors.

My goal is to make the main program by linking all the components together.

Errors:

```
gcc car.o dealer.o readline.o
dealer.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
dealer.o: In function `printList':
(.text+0x4ee): multiple definition of `printList'
car.o:car.c:(.text+0x33a): first defined here
dealer.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
dealer.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
dealer.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
dealer.o:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtbegin.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
dealer.o: In function `clearList':
(.text+0x5e2): multiple definition of `clearList'
car.o:car.c:(.text+0x42e): first defined here
dealer.o: In function `append_to_list':
(.text+0x1b4): multiple definition of `append_to_list'
car.o:car.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
dealer.o: In function `find_car':
(.text+0x3db): multiple definition of `find_car'
car.o:car.c:(.text+0x227): first defined here
dealer.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
readline.o: In function `readLine':
readline.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `readLine'
dealer.o:(.text+0x620): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
dealer.o:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in dealer.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dealer] Error 1
```

I understand what makefiles are for and what they are suppose to do but I cant seem to get this working.

Comment: gcc -c and -o don't make sense together. Use -c to tell gcc to compile a .c file into an object .o file. -o is used to *link* the multiple object files into an executable. I think gcc here is confused and trying to link each of your files into an executable of its own.

Comment: Change `readline:` to `readline.o:`, and `-o readline` to `-o readline.o` , etc.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Incorrect.  `-o` means to specify the output file name and nothing more. It is common to use `-c` and `-o` together, e.g. `gcc -o foo.obj -c foo.c`

Comment: You're right that it's possible, but I wouldn't call it common. Most Makefile just let gcc name object files the default .o.

Comment: @M.M yes I am use to seeing -o to name the output. But what is -c used for? From what I googled -c means to don't link but I am unsure what that even means.

Comment: @Jude `-c` does indeed mean to compile without linking (in other words, transform a `.c` file to an object file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile makes no sense.

```
readline: readline.h readline.c
    gcc -c -o readline readline.c
```

So your target is "readline", but you use -c, so really it is just "readline.o" - very non standard naming convention. Specifically designed to confuse? This will produce an object file (not an exe) called "readline"

```
car: car.c car.h readline.h
    gcc -c -o car car.c
```

Same as "readline". This will produce an object file (not an exe) called "car"

```
dealer.o: dealer.c car.h
    gcc -c -o dealer dealer.c
```

Not even close: the gcc is creating and object file (not an exe) called "dealer" but the target is "dealer.o". At least this time the -c is used properly - you are trying to make a ".o", it's just that the -o is wrong. Since the target is dealer.o (which is not produced) this will always run trying in vain to make dealer.o

```
dealer: car.o dealer.o readline.o
    gcc car.o dealer.o readline.o
```

No -o, so you don't create "dealer", you create "a.out". Nothing even builds car.o, dealer.o or readline.o and so it will never create anything useful. At least there is no -c so this is perhaps closer to correct...

Comment: My targets are actualy .o files so is the target in the makefile is what is outputted after the build?